# Get checkbox value even if not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the values of all checkboxes, even if they are not checked?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="2"/>
...
```

JS:

```
$("input[name='color[]']").serialize();
```

Something like the above, but I want the values even if they are not checked. Perhaps I need to put them into an array first before serialising?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want all values?

Comment: If the all checkbox is clicked, I'll want all values, even if they are not ticked.

Comment: @panthro, see my updated answer which avoids changing the original state of the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution seems to be missing, so:

```js
var serializedValues = $('input[name="color[]"]').map(function(i, e) {
  return encodeURIComponent(e.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(e.value);
}).get().join("&");
snippet.log(serializedValues);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="2" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

That's assuming you really want the same output that `seralize` would give you.

Comment: Im sorry, simple? You are doing it by hand! :) Now, better performance, yes, absolutley

Comment: @AmmarCSE: What, that's not simple? ;-) *(Yeah, that was kinda overselling it...)*

Answer (score 2):

1. Clone them to avoid altering the original state of the checkboxes
2. Set the cloned items checked to true
3. Serialize

```js
document.write($('input[name="color[]"]').clone().prop('checked', true).serialize());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="2" />
```

Comment: dont ever use document.write.

Comment: @NCA, I only use for demo purposes so readers dont have to open the console or get an annoying alert

Comment: @NCA: Would be nice if they would ever get around to [implementing this snippets feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/134069), wouldn't it? Then people wouldn't have cause to use `document.write` in answers...